# Add new attribute JSON in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an issue , I need to add new Attribute in an object Json but I found this problem in TypeScript

> error **TS2339**: Property **'condition'** does not exist on type '{ field:
>   string; value: string; operator: string; }'

This is my Code :

```
var request = [{
      field: "company_id",
      value: this.authService.getCurrentCompany().af_row_id,
      operator: '='
    }];
    if (categoryId != null) {
      request[0].condition = "AND";
    }
```

Comment: You can get dirty and do `request[0]['condition'] = "AND"` because TS is a superset of JS.

Comment: You can say that the items in array are of type `any`: `var request: any[] = [...]`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a type for `request` or you could just add a `condition` field to the object literal and have TypeScript implicitly determine the type. e.g.

```
var request = [{
    field: "company_id",
    value: this.authService.getCurrentCompany().af_row_id,
    operator: '=',
    condition: undefined
}];
if (categoryId != null) {
    request[0].condition = "AND";
}
```

Comment: I choose second solution but I had this problem :  **error TS7018: Object literal's property 'condition' implicitly has an 'any' type**.

Comment: Remove the `"noImplicitAny": true` options from your compiler flags if you don't want typescript to complain about this sort of thing. Otherwise you would have to explicitly declare a type for this

Comment: `condition: <any>undefined` or `condition: undefined as any` are also options here